# How to fix compilation in DEV-C++

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors, dev-c++

I'm on a personal project and when I go to compile my project the following message appears:

```
Makefile.win:26: recipe for target 'NightHunterServer.exe' failed
mingw32-make.exe: *** [NightHunterServer.exe] Error 1
```

my Makefile.win looks like this:

```
    # Project: NightHunterServer
    # Makefile created by Dev-C++ 5.11
    
    CPP      = g++.exe -D__DEBUG__
    CC       = gcc.exe -sdd = c ++ 11 -D__DEBUG__
    WINDRES  = windres.exe
    RES      = "../Night Hunter/Night_Hunter_Server_private.res"
    OBJ      = "../Night\ Hunter/account.o" "../Night\ Hunter/actions.o" "../Night\ Hunter/ban.o"$(RES)
    LINKOBJ  = "../Night\ Hunter/account.o" "../Night\ Hunter/actions.o" "../Night\ Hunter/ban.o"$(RES)
    LIBS     = -L"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib" -L"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib" -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system -lmysql -lboost_regex -lwsock32 -lxml2 -lmysql -lws2_32 -lboost_filesystem -lboost_thread -lz -lcryptopp -lsqlite3 -llua5.1 -leay32 -lgmp -s -g3
    INCS     = -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/include" -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include" -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/include" -I"C:/Boost"
    CXXINCS  = -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/include" -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include" -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/include" -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/include/c++" -I"C:/Boost"
    BIN      = NightHunterServer.exe
    CXXFLAGS = $(CXXINCS) -std=c++11 -fsyntax-only -g3 -g -D__USE_MYSQL__ -D__USE_SQLITE__ -D__ENABLE_SERVER_DIAGNOSTIC__ -O2 -D__CONSOLE__ -D__WAR_SYSTEM__ -D__GROUND_CACHE__ -D__ROOT_PERMISSION__
    CFLAGS   = $(INCS) -std=c++11 -fsyntax-only -g3 -g
    RM  
    
    .PHONY: all all-before all-after clean clean-custom
    
    all: all-before $(BIN) all-after
    
    clean: clean-custom
        ${RM} $(OBJ) $(BIN)
    
    $(BIN): $(OBJ)
        $(CPP) $(LINKOBJ) -o $(BIN) $(LIBS)
    
    "../Night\ Hunter/account.o": ../src/account.cpp
        $(CPP) -c ../src/account.cpp -o "../Night Hunter/account.o" $(CXXFLAGS)
    
    "../Night\ Hunter/actions.o": ../src/actions.cpp
        $(CPP) -c ../src/actions.cpp -o "../Night Hunter/actions.o" $(CXXFLAGS)
    
    
    "../Night\ Hunter/ban.o": ../src/ban.cpp
        $(CPP) -c ../src/ban.cpp -o "../Night Hunter/ban.o" $(CXXFLAGS)

    
   "../Night Hunter/Night_Hunter_Server_private.res": Night_Hunter_Server_private.rc 
    $(WINDRES) -i Night_Hunter_Server_private.rc --input-format=rc -o "../Night Hunter/Night_Hunter_Server_private.res" -O coff
```

and the error points me to this line: $ (CPP) $ (LINKOBJ) -o $ (BIN) $ (LIBS)

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: can you please paste compilation error full message(lines above this message Makefile.win:26: recipe for target 'NightHunterServer.exe' failed
mingw32-make.exe: *** [NightHunterServer.exe] Error 1)

Comment: sorry I didn't notice the last line of the Makefile.